# ucharclasses no longer does automatic Devanagari transitions in TeXLive 2021

Tags: ucharclasses, devanagari

I have recently updated to Fedora 35 and TeXLive 2021. I notice that the package `ucharclasses` no longer does automatic Devanagari transitions and I have to switch font manually. A MWE:

```
\documentclass{article}

\usepackage{fontspec}
\newfontfamily\s[Script=Devanagari]{Shobhika-Regular} % Or any other Devanagari font

\usepackage[Devanagari,Latin]{ucharclasses}
\setTransitionTo{Devanagari}{\s}
\setTransitionFrom{Devanagari}{\rmfamily}

\begin{document}
English देवनागरी English देवनागरी
\end{document}
```

The above transition commands have always worked for me before for more than 5-6 years and I have many `.tex` files using the same.

I would appreciate if someone can help with this or help file a bug report.

Answer (score 1):

This is a `ucharclasses` bug which has now been resolved.

Use `\setTransitionsForDevanagari{\s}{\rmfamily}`.

See the bug report at https://github.com/Pomax/ucharclasses/issues/38